# Variable not set properly in perl

Tags: perl, scope, subroutine

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

open $fh, "<", "$ARGV[0]" or die "Could not open file: $!";

sub getsub {
    my $sub = $_[0];
    print "sub entered for $sub\n";
    while (<$fh>) {
        if ( /\.subckt $sub/ .. /\.ends/ ) {
            print;
        }
    }
}

while (<$fh>) {
    if ( $_ =~ /^xa1/ ) {
        $line = $_;
        print "line found to be $line\n";
        while ( ( my $nxt = readline($fh) ) =~ /^\+/ ) {
            $line = $nxt;
            print "line changed to $line\n";
        }
        $line =~ s/\s+$//;
        print "last line is $line\n";
        my $sub = ( split '\s', $line )[-1];
        print "subcircuit found is $sub in $line\n";
        getsub($sub);
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to print some text between two patterns inside the `getsub` routine.  But when I try to run this I enter the subroutine but doesn't enter the if block inside the subroutine. I am trying to run it on the following file:

```
.subckt a1 x y z
  xa a b c1
  xb c d e1
  xc f g h1
.ends

.subckt c1 x y z
  xa a b f
  xb c d e
  xc f g h
.ends

.subckt e1 x y z
  xa a b c1
  xb c d k1
  xc f g h1
.ends

xa1 a s f a1
```

I want to print the contents of the file between `.subckt a1` and `.ends`.

I know this could be done by the one liners of perl on the command line, but I want to create some generalized script for different files so I need to go this way only. What is wrong with the above code.

Comment: Can you place the expected output ? We can see $line is not declared and even file handle should be my $fh since it is a variable . Try to put use strict; and use warnings; then you will come to know where the errors are present in the code.

Comment: Do you want an explanation of why your code isn't working or do you just want someone to write a working version of the script?

Comment: @ialarmedalien If you could just tell what is wrong that would be the best I don't want you to write the code for me I thought I made  that clear in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is wrong with the above code?

Two big things

1. Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY script.
2. Try not to use two `while` loops when processing a single file.

   Instead just use state variables if your file requires special processing logic at different parts of the file.

In this case, to print out the lines of a file between two markers, you simply need the [Range operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use autodie;

my $file = shift;

#open my $fh, "<", $file;
my $fh = \*DATA;

while (<$fh>) {
    if ( my $range = /^\.subckt a1/ .. /^\.ends/ ) {
        print if $range != 1 && $range !~ /E/;
    }
}

__DATA__
.subckt a1 x y z
  xa a b c1
  xb c d e1
  xc f g h1
.ends

.subckt c1 x y z
  xa a b f
  xb c d e
  xc f g h
.ends

.subckt e1 x y z
  xa a b c1
  xb c d k1
  xc f g h1
.ends

xa1 a s f a1
```

Outputs:

```
  xa a b c1
  xb c d e1
  xc f g h1
```

#### Addendum to Answer questions from comment

> I have three questions:
>
> 1. what does the value `/E/` represents in for the `$range` function?

Read the perldoc for the [Range operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

> ... The value returned by a flip-flip is either the empty string for false, or a sequence number (beginning with 1) for true. The sequence number is reset for each range encountered. The final sequence number in a range has the string "E0" appended to it, which doesn't affect its numeric value, but gives you something to search for if you want to exclude the endpoint. You can exclude the beginning point by waiting for the sequence number to be greater than 1.

Therefore the /E/ is used to exclude the end of the range, so we don't print the line that contains `.ends`.

> 2. And you used the input file as a part of the script, so what does `__DATA__` do?

I commented out the input file handle instead used a reference to `*DATA` instead.

```
#open my $fh, "<", $file;
my $fh = \*DATA;
```

`*DATA` is a special file handle that contains everything after `__DATA__` in the script.  This can be convenient way to test a script and show how to do something without needing create an actual file to load for testing.

> 3. Also, if I have a very big file should I go with this approach?

Whenever one does file processing, they should aim to process the file line by line.  That is what is done here, and therefore this would work fine for large files as well.

Comment: I have three questions: what does the value `/E/` represents in for the `$range` function. And you used the input file as a part of the script, so what does `__DATA__` do. Also, if I have a very big file should I go with this approach

Comment: Questions answered in addendum.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adjusting your code, which IMO is a little convoluted, I'll post an example using a different approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = '';  # enable paragraph mode

while (<DATA>) {
    print if /^\.subckt a1/;
}

__DATA__

.subckt a1 x y z
  xa a b c1
  xb c d e1
  xc f g h1
.ends

.subckt c1 x y z
  xa a b f
  xb c d e
  xc f g h
.ends

.subckt e1 x y z
  xa a b c1
  xb c d k1
  xc f g h1
.ends
```

Here a slightly modified version of my prior solution which loops over the file line-by-line instead od paragraph mode.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^\.subckt a1/ .. /^\.ends/) {
        print;
        print $/ if /^\.ends/
    }
}

__DATA__
.subckt a1 x y z
  xa a b f
  xb c d e
  xc f g h
.ends

.subckt a1 x y z
  xa a b c1
  xb c d e1
  xc f g h1
.ends

.subckt c1 x y z
  xa a b f
  xb c d e
  xc f g h
.ends

.subckt e1 x y z
  xa a b c1
  xb c d k1
  xc f g h1
.ends
```

I have a 3rd approach which I might post on your perlmonks thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code as shown below: I just added one more subckt a1 in InputFile and also provided expected output . Are you looking for this or something else ?

**Input File :**

```
.subckt a1 x y z
       xa a b c1
       xb c d e1
       xc f g h1
     .ends

 .subckt c1 x y z
  xa a b f
  xb c d e
  xc f g h
.ends

.subckt e1 x y z
  xa a b c1
  xb c d k1
  xc f g h1
.ends

.subckt a1 p q r
        xa a b f
        xb c d e
        xc f g h
     .ends

xa1 a s f a1
```

**Your code modified:**

```
 use strict;
    use warnings;
    open my $fh , "<", "$ARGV[0]" or die "Could not open file: $!";
     sub getsub{
        my $sub = $_[0];
        print "sub entered for $sub\n";
        my $var = do {
             local $/ = undef;
             open my $fh1 , "<", "$ARGV[0]" or die "Could not open file: $!";
             <$fh1>;
            };

        while($var =~ /\.subckt\s*$sub(.*?)\.ends/isg) {
          print $1;
        }
    }

    while  (<$fh>) {
        #print $_;
      if ($_ =~ /^xa1/) {
        my $line = $_;
        print "line found to be $line\n";
        while ((my $nxt = (readline($fh)) =~ /^\+/)) {
          $line = $nxt;
          print "line changed to $line\n";
        }
        $line =~ s/\s+$//;
        print  "last line is $line\n";
        my $sub = (split '\s', $line)[-1];
        print "subcircuit found is $sub in $line\n"; 
        getsub($sub);
      }
    }
```

**Optimized code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $document = do {
 local $/ = undef; 
 open my $fh , "<", "$ARGV[0]" or die "Could not open file: $!";
 <$fh>;
};

while($document =~ /\.subckt\s*a1(.*?)\.ends/isg)
 {
print $1;
  }
```

**Expected Output:**

```
x y z
   xa a b c1
   xb c d e1
   xc f g h1

  p q r
    xa a b f
    xb c d e
    xc f g h
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you did inside the subroutine?

Comment: After seeing your code i came to know that you wanted to get the subckt a1 from start to till .ends . So if you want to get the data between them i have done slurping for the input file and have matched the subcircuit to till end . If you do line by line matching you cannot match the .subckt to till .end as they may not be in the same line.